# GROUP BY into randomly sized chunks MySql

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to limit the number of rows that are grouped by the GROUP BY instruction?

```
SELECT earning_id FROM earnings GROUP BY ticket_id
```

For example, for this query I would like to be able to group into row groupings of a random size between 2 and 10 say?

I'm not sure what the syntax would be maybe something like:

```
GROUP BY (ticket_id, 3)
```

Basically I want to make an ajax/jquery live stats feed for my homepage. But there are so many records that I want to concatenate the data into chunks.

Comment: you can use `limit` like limit 3 at last

Comment: See this : http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp

Comment: top is Equivalent to limit

Comment: Well I kind of want it to return multiple chunks of groupings in one query not just limit the query to 3

Comment: Can you put some example data out to show exactly what you want? Note that your current SQL will bring back one earning_id for each ticket_id, but if there are multiple earning_id for that ticket_id then which one is returned is not determined.

Answer (score -1):

it will work

```
SELECT earning_id FROM earnings GROUP BY ticket_id limit 3
```

Comment: LIMIT in your query will limit rows to 3, though OP wanted to limit rows in each group...